# Create the unique ID in pandas dataframe, if the Group ID is same & Similarity Score is 100 then the UID should be same otherwise not

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have following data frame:

```
GID    Similarity Score
71      100
71      100
132     100
132      40
132     100
132      40
104      35
104      35
112       0
114       0
```

I want to create a new column named in a pandas dataframe Unique ID, it must assign the same unique ID if the GID is same and similarity score is 100. If these condition are not matched then it must assign the different Unique ID, I want the output in the below format:

```
GID    Similarity Score    UID
71      100                 900
71      100                 900
132     100                 901
132      40                 902
132     100                 901
132      40                 903
104      35                 904
104      35                 905
112       0                 906
114       0                 907
```

Comment: The logic is unclear. Wouldn't a `df.groupby(['GID', 'Similarity Score'], sort=False).ngroup().add(1000)` work? Why ido you have `1003` for the 2nd 132/40 and not `1002`? Please annotate your output to explain the logic

Comment: GID Similarity Score UID
71 100 1000
71 100 1000
132 100 1001
132 40 1002
132 100 1001
132 40 1003
132 40 1004
132 40 1005
53 100 1006
53 100 1006
104 35 1007
104 35 1007
86 42 1008
86 42 1008
188 0 1009
113 0 1010
169 0 1011
178 0 1012
166 0 1013

Comment: Please do not paste data as comment, [edit] your question

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can use a two step process to get the group number for the 100 values, and separately compute a counter for the other:

```
cols = ['GID', 'Similarity Score']

m = df['Similarity Score'].ne(100)
s1 = df[~m].groupby(cols).ngroup()
s2 = pd.Series(range(m.sum()), index=m.index[m]).add(s1.max()+1)

df['UID'] = pd.concat([s1, s2]).add(900)
```

Output:

```
   GID  Similarity Score  UID
0   71               100  900
1   71               100  900
2  132               100  901
3  132                40  902
4  132               100  901
5  132                40  903
6  104                35  904
7  104                35  905
8  112                 0  906
9  114                 0  907
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about the order of the rows, you can create a unique ID using sorting with a condition and the cumsum function.

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({
    "GID" : [71, 71, 132, 132, 132, 132, 104, 104, 112, 114],
    "Similarity Score" : [100, 100, 100, 40, 100, 40, 35, 35, 0, 0]

})

data = data.sort_values(by = ["GID", "Similarity Score"])
data["condition"] = (data["GID"] != data["GID"].shift(1)) | (data["Similarity Score"] != data["Similarity Score"].shift(1)) | (data["Similarity Score"] != 100)
data["UID"] = data["condition"].cumsum() + 899
data = data.drop(columns = ["condition"])
```

You can also resort by index afterward to get back the order of the rows (though the ID number won't be following the row order) :

```
data = data.sort_index()
```

Answer (score 0):

@mozway solution is fine, here is an alternative:

```py
from itertools import count, islice

counter = count(900)
def assign_uid(group: pd.DataFrame):
    if group["Similarity Score"].unique() == [100]:
        # same UID for all rows
        uids = next(counter)
    else:
        # unique UID for all rows
        uids = list(islice(counter, len(group)))
    return group.assign(UID=uids)


cols = ["GID", "Similarity Score"]
df.groupby(cols, group_keys=False, sort=False).apply(assign_uid)
```

```
   GID  Similarity Score  UID
0   71               100  900
1   71               100  900
2  132               100  901
3  132                40  902
4  132               100  901
5  132                40  903
6  104                35  904
7  104                35  905
8  112                 0  906
9  114                 0  907
```